# Where is the name of a database file to be created specified?

Tags: python, flask, sqlite

From http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/database/

> ```
> import sqlite3
> import click
> from flask import current_app, g
> from flask.cli import with_appcontext
> def get_db():
>     if 'db' not in g:
>         g.db = sqlite3.connect(
>             current_app.config['DATABASE'],
>             detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES
>         )
>         g.db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
>     return g.db
> def close_db(e=None):
>     db = g.pop('db', None)
>     if db is not None:
>         db.close()
>
> ...
>
> def init_db():
>     db = get_db()
>     with current_app.open_resource('schema.sql') as f:
>         db.executescript(f.read().decode('utf8'))
> @click.command('init-db')
> @with_appcontext
> def init_db_command():
>     """Clear the existing data and create new tables."""
>     init_db()
>     click.echo('Initialized the database.')
>
> ...
>
> def init_app(app):
>     app.teardown_appcontext(close_db)
>     app.cli.add_command(init_db_command)
>
> ...
>
> def create_app():
>     app = ...
>     # existing code omitted
>     from . import db
>     db.init_app(app)
>     return app
> ```
>
> Run the init-db command:
>
> ```
> flask init-db
> Initialized the database.
> ```
>
> There will now be a `flaskr.sqlite` file in the instance folder in
>   your project.

I am surprised that `flaskr.sqlite` seems created without being specified any where. How it is specified to be created?
How is the name of the file `flaskr.sqlite` specified to sqlite3 when creating the file?

If using sqlite directly without flask, how can I create such a file named `flaskr.sqlite`?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not very clear but this line is what you are looking for i guess: `current_app.config['DATABASE']`

Comment: Thanks. If using sqlite3 directly without flask, how can I specify the name of the file to be created?

Comment: The database name is the first argument to `sqlite3.connect()`.  i.e. `sqlite3.connect('example.db')`.

Comment: When you connect to an SQLite database file that does not exist, SQLite creates a new database for you. Source: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/creating-database/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the previous page of the Tutorial, [Application Setup](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/factory/), where `app.config.from_mapping()` happens.

Comment: Updated link for Application Setup -> https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/factory/